# how to calculate button press time in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

There are various buttons in my form and for each button press an action is associated with it.I want to measure the time between button is pressed and released (in millisecs).How can I do it for each button.

Comment: I don't understand you want to calculate how long it took to click a button or how long it took to execute the handler code/process ?

Comment: why don't you use `button.MouseDown()` and `button.MouseUp()` events?

Comment: That seems like a strange thing to capture, but you can look at the MouseDown, MouseUp, KeyDown, KeyUp events of a button. Get a datetime object in the down and calculate the difference in the up event.

Comment: Find utc time differences in button.MouseDown() and button.MouseUp() events

Comment: yes,I want to calculate how long the button was pressed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Form_Load event you can iterate all buttons and dynamically attach Stopwatch to each of them, then handle their MouseDown and MouseUp events:

```
this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(button =>
{
    button.Tag = new Stopwatch();
    button.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(button_MouseDown);
    button.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(button_MouseUp);
});
```

And the functions:

```
void button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch watch = ((sender as Button).Tag as Stopwatch);
    watch.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("This button was clicked for " + watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " milliseconds");
    watch.Reset();
}

void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((sender as Button).Tag as Stopwatch).Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can measure the time span using [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), or use a *performance profiler*, like
[Equatec](http://eqatec.com/Profiler/), which has a free option too.

`StopWatch` relative [StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew.aspx) and [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.stop.aspx) mthods can inject, in front and at the end of the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the `KeyDown` and `MouseDown` for the down event and the `KeyUp` and `MouseUp` for the up event.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(button1_down);
        button1.MouseDown+=new MouseEventHandler(button1_down);

        button1.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(button1_Up);
        button1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(button1_Up);
    }

    void button1_down(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
    }

    private void button1_Up(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
    }
```