# mvvm command is called by long-pressing a button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a button

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

But MyCommand is being hit when I long-press the button as well as when I just click it.  Is there any way around this?

thanks

Comment: so what you really need? Be clear with the problem.

Comment: I want for the command not to be hit when I long-press the button...

Comment: Are you running the application on emulator? Try it with device and check

Comment: No, I'm running it on a device.

Comment: use mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932423/how-to-calculate-button-press-time-in-c

Comment: @DhavalPatel that is winforms, this is wpf using MVVM - *very* different!

Comment: So what you can also use it in mvvm using eventtrigger

Comment: This is not WPF, rather silverlight. Plus, this is a normal and expected behavior, a button tap is a combination of a touch down + touch up and it doesn't care about how much time happened between the two. If you want to change this behavior you need to implement your own event trigger system.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is the following:

1. Reference the System.Windows.Interactivity dll.
2. Define the namespace in your xaml code:

   xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
3. Then in your xaml code wire up this event trigger:

> ```
>    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
>        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap" SourceName="btnTest">
>            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSomething}" />
>        </i:EventTrigger>
>    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
> ```

The `EventName` in this case is "Tap", the `SourceName` is the x:Name of the button you want to watch. Like this:

```
<Button Content="Click me" x:Name="btnTest"/>
```

Then in your ViewModel, you can wire it up to an ICommand, I typically use a RelayCommand:

```
    private ICommand _DoSomething;
    public ICommand DoSomething
    {
        get
        {
            if (_DoSomething == null)
            {
                _DoSomething = new RelayCommand(DoSomethingExecute);
            }

            return _DoSomething;
        }
    }

    private void DoSomethingExecute()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("btnTest on the tap event");
            });
    }
```

I tested, only the tap event is captured, not the long press event.